# javascript Alert to confirm if value entered twice

Tags: javascript

I have a form:

```
// 10 times
<input type="text" name="cityname" class="autocompletecity">
<input type="text" name="cityID" class="autocompletecityID">
```

When I enter the city name, it autocompletes the city name and the cityID from database with this code:

```
<?php  for ($i = 0; $i < 10; $i++) { /*in the field class add $i */  ?>
  $(function() {
    function log( message ) {
      $( "<div>" ).text( message ).prependTo( "#log" );
      $( "#log" ).scrollTop( 1 );
    }
    $( ".autocompletecity<?php echo $i ?>" ).autocomplete({
      source: "/*path to json*/",
      select: function( event, ui ) {
        var item = ui.item;
        if(item) {
          $(".autocompletecityID<?php echo $i ?>").val(item.cityID);
          $(this).val(item.value +' ' + item.country);
          return false;
        }
      }

      //code from J.D.
      select: function( event, ui ) {
        var item = ui.item;
        if(item) {
          $('input[name="cityID"]').each(function(index, element) {
            var $element = $(element);
            if ($element.value() == item.cityID) {
              alert('This city has already been selected');
            }
          });
        }
      }
    })
    .autocomplete( "instance" )._renderItem = function( ul, item ) {
      return $( "<li>" )
        .append( "<a>" +item.value + " " +item.country + "</a>" )
        .appendTo( ul );
    };
  });

<?php } ?>
```

After it autocompletes the cityID, I would like to show an alert box if same cityID has alredy been entered: Click OK to confirm or Cancel to clear the cityname and cityID with repeated entry. 
I tried to search in the jqueryui, but no luck...

Thanks!!

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
select: function( event, ui ) {
  var item = ui.item;
  if(item) {
    $('input[name="cityID"]').each(function(index) {
      var $element = $(this);
      if ($element.value() == item.cityID) {
        alert('This city has already been selected');
      }
    });
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks jd! I'm new at javascript, so I edited my question with code... could you please get a look give me an hand to integrate it with your code? Thanks!!

Comment: I've edited the answer based on your edit. Maybe it's not 100% accurate so you'll have to tweak it a little.

Comment: Thanks, but still not working, still not sure where to insert it...sorry! I've edited my question with your code.

Comment: I've updated the code, check if it works now and console.log($element.value()); I think maybe autocomplete creates a new input and saves cityID there. Check in your html if there are additional inputs.